# Ionic Radio-group Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm moving my Ionic over to Ionic 4 and am having trouble with the Firebase database integration.

Problem: Every time I try to push new information to the Firebase database under the user's uid, I get

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

My code for the html:

```html
<ion-content no-bounce padding id="master">
    <div class="list">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input class="title" type="text" placeholder="Add your title here" [(ngModel)]="list.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      
        <ion-list no-lines [(ngModel)]="list.color">
          <ion-radio-group>
          <p class="radio-label">Pick your list colour</p>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label class="labelC">Light Coral</ion-label>
              <ion-radio class="radioC" slot="start" value="#f55f7c"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label class="labelY">Sandy Brown</ion-label>
              <ion-radio class="radioY" slot="start" value="#ffcb53"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label class="labelB">Aquamarine</ion-label>
              <ion-radio class="radioB" slot="start" value="#85dec8">Aquamarine</ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-radio-group>
          </ion-list>
    </div>
    
    <div class="button"><ion-button (click)="createNewList1(list)">ADD LIST</ion-button></div>
</ion-content>
```

Here's the ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// Firebase imports
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Model import
import { List } from '../models/list.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-list',
  templateUrl: './add-list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-list.page.scss'],
})
export class AddListPage implements OnInit {

  list = {} as List;
  newListRef$: AngularFireList<List>;
  listId: any;
  userId: any;

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.newListRef$ = this.db.list(this.userId + '/lists');
  }

  createNewList1(list: List) {
    this.newListRef$.push({
      name: this.list.name,
      color: this.list.color
    });
    this.router.navigateByUrl('main/' + this.userId);
  }
}
```

I've also referred to the new ion-button rules that Ionic has set up.

But I keep getting errors...

(This code ran perfectly without errors before I started moving it to Ionic 4)

**Edit:** I'm thinking it has to do with being unable to read the value of list.color from the Radio-Group. I'm getting a click error of

> ERROR Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'WCoOMVhPUZOVPFFhmTpSul2Mtxr1.lists.color'

where 'WCoOMVh...' is the user uid and 'lists', I'm assuming is the node I'm pointing to.

Comment: Link says Page Not Found.

Comment: Try adding a `name` attribute to all the tags where you've used `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @SiddAjmera, could you please clarify what you mean by a "name" attribute?

Comment: Something like `<ion-input class="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Add your title here" [(ngModel)]="list.name"></ion-input>`